# sagepay / authenticate and authorise / 115% calculation rules

Tags: authentication, opayo

I've just had an issue where an authenticated payment failed to authorise with the following error:

StatusDetail=4044 : This Authorise would exceed maximum allowed value.

The original amount was 119.46. If you multiply that by 1.15 to add on 15% you get 137.379 which I would expect to round up to 137.38. I can only authorise the payment if I authorise the rounded down value of 137.37.

Could someone please confirm the calculation method used when determining what is available to authorise?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that as the Authorise is up to 15% over the transaction value, it must not exceed 15% even by a fraction. So round under rather than over.

119.46 x 0.15 = 17.919 + 119.46 = 137.37.9 The Amount to Authorise will be 137.37 if you are being presented with 4044 for the amount of 137.88.